# How to select object with foreign_key pointing to nothing?

Tags: sql

I have two models, Task and TaskAssignment. TaskAssignment has a foreign key `task_id` pointing to task.

I had an issue with my site that deleting Task was not deleting TaskAssignment. So TaskAssignment still exists and have a `task_id` pointing to nothing.

I want to write a query to search for TaskAssignment with this problem.
Sorry for not posting any basic query but I'm blocked. It's been a few months that I don't work with SQL and I'm rusty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both tables together the same way you do, and simply check if the `id` on the Task table is `null`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TaskAssignment ta
  LEFT JOIN Task t ON t.id = ta.task_id
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a foreign key from TaskAssignment to Task, and you managed to delete the parent Task but leave the child TaskAssignment behind, then the FK must have been specified as ON DELETE SET NULL* which would imply that all you need to do is

```
SELECT * FROM TaskAssignment WHERE task_id IS NULL
```

*it might alternatively (unusually) have been configured to set default if your dbms supports such, in which case adjust the query to seek the default value

Comment: The problem is the Task is being deleted and nothing is done with TaskAssignment.  The TaskAssignment is not being deleted and the task_id is not being updated to NULL.

Comment: Well it's happening on the system I'm working with. How? I don't have a clue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know of no database that permits a foreign key to operate like that, because it would do a very poor job of ensuring "referential integrity". The only way to have a deletable parent when children exist is to *not* have a foreign key; the question makes it clear there is a foreign key, which will either operate in "when parent is deleted also delete child", "when parent is deleted set child id to null so it no longer references a nonexistent parent" or "refuse to delete parent when child records exist" mode.

Comment: I was taking a better look at the database and you're right. It looks like task_id is not a foreign key, it appears to be just a normal attribute. Sorry. I did not build this system. It is something I started working on a few weeks ago and it looked really strange the way this two models are behaving.
Sorry again and thanks for your help.